# Azure Cosmos DB Quickstart example not working

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I created a new Azure CosmosDB (Gremlin API), then downloaded the Quickstart example:

[image: CosmosDB Gremlin API Quickstart]

when I run it, this Exception appears:

> JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I checked, the endpoint and authKey are set.

```
    public async Task RunAsync(DocumentClient client)
    {
        // the line below throws the Exception
        Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "graphdb" });

        DocumentCollection graph = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("graphdb"),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = "Persons" },
            new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });
```

[image: Screenshot]

The Quickstard sample comes with endpoint and authKey filled in on the App.config file:
[image: App.config]

How to solve it?

Comment: This is not the actual line of code throwing the exception. Try putting a breakpoint at start of RunAsync method and  see which line throws the error

Comment: OK, I put the breakpoint and the exception happens on       Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "graphdb" });

Comment: Try with just `var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "graphdb" });`...also can you show us the definition of `DocumentClient`?

Comment: Tried var database, it is ResourceResponse<Database>, got same Exception // DocumentClient is from Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client assembly

Comment: But you need to set the client somewhere, and to that client, you need to pass your azure cosmosdb credentials...without that step you can´t do anything.

Comment: The Quickstard sample comes with endpoint and authKey filled in on the App.config file.

Comment: I suggest showing us the interaction between your client and documentDB. This seems like a `json` parsing issue - what are you sending to and reading from documentdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the Endpoint to this format `https://<account-name>.documents.azure.com:443/`.

This is a current issue with the newly created Gremlin accounts and will be addressed shortly in the Quickstarts.

Comment: as written here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-dotnet-getting-started/issues/9